# What is Java's equivalent to Kotlin's covariant and contra-variant modifiers?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, covariance, contravariance

Consider the following Kotlin interface:

```kotlin
interface Box<out T : SomeType> {
    val item: T
}
```

Implementing this with Kotlin would look something like this:

```kotlin
data class BoxImpl<out T : SomeType>(override val item: T) : Box<T>
```

Now I want to convert that interface to Java:

```java
public interface Box<T extends SomeType> {
    T getItem();
}
```

But implementing this in Kotlin causes a problem:

```
data class BoxImpl<out T : SomeType>(private val item: T) : Box<T> {

    override fun getItem(): T {
        return item
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Kotlin compiler complains that `T` is **invariant** on the Java interface, but **covariant** on the implementation.

So, how do you specify `out` (covariant) variance in Java?

Additionally, how would you specify `in` (contra-variant) variance?

Comment: As both answers indicate "Java doesn’t support declaration-site variance like Kotlin does". Notice [JEP-300](https://openjdk.org/jeps/300) proposes it, so maybe in a distant future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't have declaration-site variance like Kotlin does. That is, you cannot specify the variance of a type when you *declare* it. However, it does have use-site variance - you *can* specify the variance when you *use* a type, as the type of a variable, for example.

For example,

```
// Kotlin
var foo: SomeGenericType<out T>
var bar: SomeGenericType<in T>
```

is similar to:

```
// Java
SomeGenericType<? extends T> foo;
SomeGenericType<? super T> bar;
```

(The mnemonic for this is [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).)

A crucial difference though, is that you can pass `null`s into methods of the Java `bar` variable,

```
bar.someMethod(null);
```

But you cannot pass anything into the Kotlin `bar` - it literally takes `Nothing`!

If you are trying to use a generic type from Java in your Kotlin code, I think you'd have to make it `@UnsafeVariance` to suppress the compiler error for now.

```
// Of course, only do this if you are sure that Box is covariant!
data class BoxImpl<out T : SomeType>(private val item: T) : Box<@UnsafeVariance T>
```

There are also discussions about adding the ability to annotate Java type parameters so that the Kotlin compiler knows about their variance. See [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41062/Allow-Java-classes-to-specify-declaration-site-variance) and [this](https://github.com/jspecify/jspecify/issues/72). Hopefully we can get that some day in the future. Though this doesn't change the fact that there is no declaration-site variance in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn’t support declaration-site variance like Kotlin does. It only supports use-site variance. In other words, variance can only be used on variable and parameter types, not in class/interface definitions.

So in Java, you would specify your interface and class definitions without variance, and every time you need variance, you would declare the variable with it.

Covariance uses `? extends`, and contravariance use `? super`, for example:

```java
Box<? extends Number> numberBox = new BoxImpl(1);
```